# Sequence of functions and its graph

Tags: uniform-convergence, arzela-ascoli

Consider a sequence of functions f<sub>n</sub> in C<sup>0</sup>. Suppose G<sub>n</sub> of f<sub>n</sub> is a compact subset of R<sup>2</sup>.

Then prove f<sub>n</sub> converges uniformly as n->  ∞ if and only if the sequence G<sub>n</sub> in K(R<sup>2</sup>) converges to the graph of the function f in C<sup>0</sup>.

I know we have to use Arzela-Ascoli but i don't know how to apply it. Can anyone help?

Comment: Please re-write your def'ns so that they make sense. And clarify your Q. I can't tell exactly what this asks.

Comment: just edited it, is this fine?